# About auxiliary verbs

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I googled "auxiliary verbs" just in order to  check if there is something I do not know about them and I found this site.But I think there is misleading information on the site.

For example it is written on the site:

> Do / does / did Do is common for forming questions and making
>   negatives.
>
> Did is used for do and does in the past tense. Do and does is never
>   used for the past.
>
> In statements
>
> I **do** my homework.
>
> You **do** the laundry.
>
> We **do** the washing up.
>
> They **do** yoga.
>
> He/she **does** the cleaning.

But I don't think **these**  "do/does" in **the example sentences** are auxiliary verb, they are main verb.Could you check the page please? or am I the one who reads wrongly?

http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/what-are-auxiliary-verbs

Comment: Do you have any reason for needing this? IE a project or something? It will help me to better understand how to help you.

Comment: [Use of **do** as main verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support#Use_of_do_as_main_verb)

Comment: @CopperKettle So I am right, aren't I

Comment: None of your examples use ***do*** as an "auxiliary verb". But in every case it would be possible to add another ***do*** after the highlighted term (the first one *would* then become an auxiliary). The first such example *("I do do my homework!")* would be an emphatic refutation of a statement like *"You never do your homework!"* Or you could use ***have*** as an auxiliary - *"I **have** done my homework!"*

Comment: @Murat - I'm busy at the moment but I guess you might try to find some list of auxiliary verb features, some "linguistic tests" helping to distinguish a main (lexical) verb from an auxiliary.

Comment: @CopperKettle It is ok.No need really.Thank you .FumbleFingers conforms I am right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about the validity of information on a random website. It is also asking SE/ELL users to proofread sentences from a random website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original Poster is quite right. *DO* in these examples is lexical or 'main verb' *DO*, not the auxiliary verb *DO*:

> I **do** my homework.
>
> You **do** the laundry.
>
> We **do** the washing up.
>
> They **do** yoga.
>
> He/she **does** the cleaning.

We can show this by doing some tests. To make negatives in English we put *not* or *n't* after the auxiliary verb. But this will not work with these sentences:

- *I don't my homework. (ungrammatical)
- *You don't the laundry. (ungrammatical)
- *We do not the washing up. (ungrammatical)
- *They don't yoga. (ungrammatical)
- *She doesn't the cleaning. (ungrammatical)

Also we cannot make questions here by inverting the subject and *DO*. If *DO* was an auxiliary here then this would be possible but it itn't:

- *Do I my homework? (ungrammatical)
- *Do you the laundry? (ungrammatical)
- *Do you the washing up? (ungrammatical)
- *Do they yoga? (ungrammatical)
- *Does she the cleaning? (ungrammatical)

If we want to make grammatical questions and negatives here we need to use the auxiliary verb *DO* as well as the lexical verb *DO*:

**negatives**

- I don't do my homework.
- You don't do the laundry.
- We do not do the washing up.
- They don't do yoga.
- She doesn't do the cleaning.

**questions**

- Do I do my homework?
- Do you do the laundry?
- Do you do the washing up?
- Do they do yoga?
- Does she do the cleaning?

Also if we want to give emphatic versions of the sentence we need to add an auxiliary *DO* to the sentences:

- I *do* do my homework!
- You *do* do the laundry!
- We *do* do the washing up!
- They *do* do yoga!
- She *does* do the cleaning!

All of this data shows that the Original Poster's examples use main verb *DO* and not the auxiliary verb.

The site that the OP links to is published by a language school company. Never go to one of these schools!

**Note** For some people *yoga* seems to be a verb. In this case, *They do yoga* would be an emphatic version of *they yoga*! Don't copy this in writing because it isn't standard (yet!)